# error and weird vlaue of 4cc codec using cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using python 3, cv2 version 4.1.2.30
I have loaded a video and extracted some info about it:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('shop.avi')

#use opencv2 API to query movie info

#movie width,height in pixels, length in frames and encoded format.
fw = int(cap.get(3))
fh = int(cap.get(4))
len_ = int(cap.get(7))
fps = int(cap.get(5))
ccodec = int(cap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
print (fw,'x',fh, ',', len,' frames,',' codec=',ccodec)
```

it gived back this error:

```
module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC'
```

I tried using an int instead:

```
ccodec = int(cap.get(6))
```

and it gives back the value 1145656920, which is not 4 cc long.

what is the problem?

Comment: Try `ccodec = int(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC))`

Comment: name 'CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC' is not defined

Comment: Drop the `CV_` prefix... IIRC that's been changed since 3.0. https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d

Comment: `1145656920` is a 32bit integer -- exactly enough to store the 4 bytes of the 4cc code. It says `DIVX`.